# Remove content inside span

Tags: python, web-scraping

It looks quite easy, but I haven't managed to find a solution.
I tried other proposed solutions, like: `span.clear()` but didn't do it.

**Web's structure:**

```
<div class="details">           
  <h2>Public function</h2>  
  <div class="token">
    <h2>Name person</h2>
    <h3>Name person</h3>
    <p>
        <span>NO</span>NO</p>
    <p>
        <span>Time of Death:</span>13:38:00</p>
```

**Result:**

```
Time of Death: 13:38:00
```

**Desired result:**

```
13:38:00
```

**My code:**

```
whole_section = soup.find('div', {'class':"token"}) # Access to whole section
name_person = whole_section.h2.text  # Select person's name, inside "h2" tag.
time_decease = whole_section.h3.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.text # Because ther's no tag, I'd to use "next_sibling".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't really ever recommend traversing the DOM by repeatedly trying to get the next sibling - in my experience, every time you do this it makes your script more and more prone to breakages for the smallest changes in the source HTML.

Instead, find the parent `<p></p>` you're after by using a `lambda` function to filter based on the contents of the `<p></p>` itself (the `'Time of Death:'` string, specifically); then loop through the child elements of that `<p></p>` element and remove the `<span></span>` to extract what you're after:

```
html = '''<div class="details">           
  <h2>Public function</h2>  
  <div class="token">
    <h2>Name person</h2>
    <h3>Name person</h3>
    <p>
        <span>NO</span>NO</p>
    <p>
        <span>Time of Death:</span>13:38:00</p>
  </div>
</div>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

whole_section = soup.find('div', {'class':"token"}) # Access to whole section
name_person = whole_section.h2.text  # Select person's name, inside "h2" tag.
time_decease = whole_section.find(lambda element: element.name == 'p' and 'Time of Death:' in element.text)
for span in time_decease.find_all('span'):
  span.decompose()

print(name_person)
print(time_decease.text)
```

[<sup>repl.it</sup>](https://replit.com/@esqew/LastVerticalNetworking#main.py)

Comment: Your solution works, but when I try to implement the same method to get the other contents I'm interested in, it breaks. After the 4th filter-loop it says "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'". The strange thing is that is able to retrieve a couple of contents before it displays the previous error message. Do you know why?

Comment: It breaks probably because it's specifically geared for the example case you provided in your original question. You won't be able to just apply it one to one to other cases without performing some tweaking. Without seeing *exactly* what your use cases are, it's not really possible for me to "*know why*". Update your question to include this pertinent information, what you've tried for each scenario, and where you're getting stuck for each.

Comment: If I don't manage to find a solution on my own, I'll ask another question. Thank you. I was asking because the other cases are exactly the same as posted in the example( just COPY and PASTE everything after h3 tag). I'll accept your answer.